# how to write full text search in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have written a method and model for keyword search. But  unfortunately I am getting the output which are matched with my keyword and also which does not have any match with the keyword I typed.

Here is My Code:

**controller.php :**

```
       function suggestions()
{
        $this->load->model('Booksmodel');
        $term = $this->input->post('term',TRUE); 
        $rows = $this->Booksmodel->GetAutocomplete(array('keyword' => $term)); 
        $json_array = array();
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        array_push($json_array, $row->book_title);
        array_push($json_array, $row->auth_firstname);
        array_push($json_array, $row->isbn);  

        echo json_encode($json_array);
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: What does $this->db->last_query(); produce? (run after the query is completed)

Comment: @Danny  Pardon me! What do you mean?   i have clearly mention in my question  `eg. if i typed keyword like "grisham" as author last name then i am getting the all other data(book_title,auth_firstname,isbn) as output including "grisham"(i.e auth_lastname)`

Comment: Add 
echo $this->db->last_query();
Just after $query = $this->db->get('bookdetails');
And post the output

Comment: @xelber what it will do?

Comment: Also what does the json_encode output look like?

Comment: You are using CI DB Abstraction layer, when you call ->get, it will construct an SQL based on you select, or_like etc.

Comment: $this->db->last_query(); will show you what the mysql query looks like that codeigniter generated.

Comment: @xelber Now i am travelling, i will let you know after sometime

Comment: Because you have use same keyword($options['keyword']) for all other fields.Thats why it is showing all other data(book_title,auth_firstname,isbn) as output including "$options['keyword']".so if it find that keyword in any other field it shows that row in your result.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/233874/

Comment: @xelber nothing is displaying on the screen. i am submiting my keyword search form with ajax.

Comment: @Danny  nothing is displaying on the screen. i am submiting my keyword search form with ajax.

Comment: Wont stop you from echo, just use firebug or similar to see the output

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Added another parameter, none, to `'like'` function ):

```
 function GetAutocomplete($options = array())
  { 
    $this->load->database();   
    $this->db->limit('10');  
    $this->db->select('book_title,auth_firstname,isbn,auth_lastname,publisher_name');    
    $this->db->like('book_title', $options['keyword'], 'none');
    $this->db->or_like('auth_firstname', $options['keyword'], 'none'); 
    $this->db->or_like('isbn', $options['keyword'], 'none');
    $this->db->or_like('auth_lastname', $options['keyword'], 'none');
    $this->db->or_like('publisher_name', $options['keyword'], 'none'); 

    $query = $this->db->get('bookdetails');
      return $query->result();
    }
```

'none' will prevent it from using wildcard (`%`) in like function.

Comment: sorry it is not like what i wanted. Please read my question once again.

Comment: Yes i tried as it is your code. But i am getting output as i mention in my above code is producing.        I found similar question, but i could not write my query ,as they are explained here.  http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/134133/#662060